# How can I implement two sort keys in Dynamo DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I’m building a database using  DynamoDB on AWS.

I am using variable X as a partition key, and variable Y as a sort key.

I also have a variable Z which i need as a second sort key.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Generally in DynamoDB you can create [Local Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) if you need alternative sort key:

> To give your application a choice of sort keys, you can create one or
> more local secondary indexes on an Amazon DynamoDB table and issue
> Query or Scan requests against these indexes.

Important things to note are that LSIs c**an only be created when you create your main table**, and they **can't be deleted** later.

You can have max 5 LSI per table.

Answer (score 4):

This is where you might use an LSI or GSI, but if this are queries you are not doing often and/or not at a high velocity, or the returned set with the PK and SK is small enough, you could just do a filter expression on the query results. Yes this is a little waste, but the cost of that waste could be less than the literal cost to having and maintain a secondary index. I cannot answer if this is the case for your workload though.